# Are Func and Action Delegates in C# used by companies?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action, func

I really wonder if the Func and Action delegates are used by developing companies. 
And do they use it for events? I know it's a strange question but I already asked it to my teacher and many other people but nobody could give me an answer.

Comment: Of course. We use them often.

Comment: Yes, we use them all the time. Not for events, though; we use EventHandler and similar delegate types for those.

Comment: Considering that the whole LINQ is based on the `Func<>` delegate, it would be difficult to not use it at least implicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C#, `Action` and `Func` are extremely useful tools for reducing duplication in code and decreasing coupling. And reduce duplication and make code reusable is important to any company

It is a shame that many developers shy away from them because they don’t really understand them.

Adding Action and Func to your toolbox is a very important step in improving your C# code.

As great exmaple of Using them : `Linq` is based on `Action` and `Func` and `Predicate`

Comment: Thanks for the answer it's exactlly what I wanted to be confirmed! And I learned something new. I didn't knew that Linq was based on those delegates.

Comment: Crickey! Yous guys are killing the English language. LOL

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of the power of these constructs, which illustrates for me the emptiness of the "junior devs might not understand it" argument.

If you have an `Organisation` class, which contains a collection of `Department` objects, and if the `Department` class contains a collection of `Employee` objects, how do you get the full set of employees for an organisation?

You could loop through the objects and build up a collection:

```
var allEmployees = new List<Employee>();
foreach (var department in organisation.Departments)
{
    foreach (var employee in department.Employees)
    {
        allEmployees.Add(employee);
    }
}
```

or you could simply use the single statement

```
var allEmployees = organisation.Departments.SelectMany(d => d.Employees).ToArray();
```

This code is terser, and less susceptible to human error, than the manual loop, and the immutability of the resultant array is less prone to bugs than the mutable list.  To obtain these benefits, it is necessary to be comfortable with the use of lambdas to represent `Func` and `Action` constructs.

Comment: That's a really great explanation. Thanks very much. I use Linq all the time but I never thought to use it to do that. Does the single statement have any performance benefits over its counterpart?

Comment: Generally speaking, Linq doesn't offer a performance improvement in itself.  It's really just an abstraction, and a delayed execution, of the `IEnumerable` `Reset` and `MoveNext` functions.  However, the benefits, as I see them, are two-fold: first, it gives you a common interface for all of the most common mapping and aggregation operations on collections; secondly, the abstraction means that you can use Linq to write smart adapters that can plan strategies for working across system boundaries.  ORMs like Entity Framework are a classic example of this capability.